# QT configure with xp support error

Tags: qt, compilation

I want to build(with MinGW 5.3.0 32bit) my QT(qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0) with Xp support

```
configure -target xp -static -qmake -opensource -nomake examples -no-opengl -platform win32-g++ -openssl-linked -I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -L C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib OPENSSL_LIBS="-llibeay32 -lssleay32 -lgdi32"
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: Unknown command line option '-target'.
Qmake failed, return code 3
```

Comment: IIRC xp is not supported from Qt 5.6 and up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Qt 5.6 LTS` supports Windows XP until March 2019. Since Qt 5.7 release Qt supports Windows 7 and upwards.